# How to choose between asIterable() vs asSequence()?

Tags: kotlin

`Iterable` and `Sequence` seem awfully similar, and the collection classes all expose both `asIterable()` and `asSequence()`.

Are there any semantic or performance considerations to bear in mind when picking one or the other? What circumstances would lead you to prefer one over the other?

More generally, why use an `Iterable` vs a `Sequence`?

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate catch! None of the suggestions hit the mark for me. >_<